# Calculate ellipse size in relation to distance from center point

Tags: processing

I want to achieve a slow fade in size on every collapse into itself. In other words, when the circle is at its biggest, the ellipses will be at the largest in size and conversely the opposite for the retraction. So far I am trying to achieve this affect by remapping the cSize from the distance of the center point, but somewhere along the way something is going wrong. At the moment I am getting a slow transition from small to large in ellipse size, but the inner ellipses are noticeably larger. I want an equal distribution of size amongst all ellipses in relation to center point distance.

I've simplified the code down to 4 ellipses rather than an array of rows of ellipses in order to hopefully simplify this example. This is done in the for (int x = -50; x <= 50; x+=**100**).

I've seen one or two examples that slightly does what I want, but is more or less static. This example is kind of similar because the ellipse size gets smaller or larger in relation to the mouse position

[Distance2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UUdu.png)

Here is an additional diagram of the grid of ellipses I am trying to create, In addition, I am trying to scale that "square grid" of ellipses by a center point.

[Multiple ellipses + Scale by center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5gq9.png)

Any pointers?

```java
float cSize;
float shrinkOrGrow;

void setup() {
    size(640, 640);
    noStroke();
    smooth();
    fill(255);
}

void draw() {
    background(#202020);
    translate(width/2, height/2);

    if (cSize > 10) {
      shrinkOrGrow = 0;
    } else if (cSize < 1 ) {
      shrinkOrGrow = 1;
}

    if (shrinkOrGrow == 1) {
      cSize += .1;
    } else if (shrinkOrGrow == 0) {
      cSize -= .1;
}
    for (int x = -50; x <= 50; x+=100) {
    for (int y = -50; y <= 50; y+=100) {
    float d = dist(x, y, 0, 0);    
    float fromCenter = map(cSize, 0, d, 1, 10);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(x, y);
  rotate(radians(d + frameCount));
  ellipse(x, y, fromCenter, fromCenter);
  popMatrix();
}
}
}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you simplify your example. Can you narrow it down to just using a single ellipse, just to demonstrate your problem? Maybe post a screenshot of what you're expecting vs what happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you're passing into the `map()` function don't make a lot of sense to me:

```java
float fromCenter = map(cSize, 0, d, 1, 100);
```

The `cSize` variable bounces from `1` to `10` independent of anything else. The `d` variable is the distance of each ellipse to the center of the circle, **but that's going to be static for each one** since you're using the `rotate()` function to "move" the circle, which never actually moves. That's based only on the `frameCount` variable, which you never use to calculate the size of your ellipses.

In other words, the position of the ellipses and their size are completely unrelated in your code.

You need to refactor your code so that the size is based on the distance. I see two main options for doing this:

**Option 1:** Right now you're moving the circles on screen using the `translate()` and `rotate()` functions. You could think of this as the camera moving, not the ellipses moving. So if you want to base the size of the ellipse on its distance from some point, you have to get the distance of the transformed point, not the original point.

Luckily, Processing gives you the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions for figuring out where a point will be after you transform it.

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```java
  for (int x = -50; x <= 50; x+=100) {
    for (int y = -50; y <= 50; y+=100) {
      pushMatrix();

      //transform the point
      //in other words, move the camera
      translate(x, y);
      rotate(radians(frameCount));

      //get the position of the transformed point on the screen
      float screenX = screenX(x, y);
      float screenY = screenY(x, y);

      //get the distance of that position from the center
      float distanceFromCenter = dist(screenX, screenY, width/2, height/2);

      //use that distance to create a diameter
      float diameter = 141 - distanceFromCenter;

      //draw the ellipse using that diameter
      ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
```

**Option 2:** Stop using `translate()` and `rotate()`, and use the positions of the ellipses directly.

You might create a class that encapsulates everything you need to move and draw an ellipse. Then just create instances of that class and iterate over them. You'd need some basic trig to figure out the positions, but you could then use them directly.

Here's a little example of doing it that way:

```java
ArrayList<RotatingEllipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<RotatingEllipse>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.75));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.75));
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  for (RotatingEllipse e : ellipses) {
    e.stepAndDraw();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(mouseX, mouseY));
}

void mouseDragged() {
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(mouseX, mouseY));
}

class RotatingEllipse {

  float rotateAroundX;
  float rotateAroundY;
  float distanceFromRotatingPoint;
  float angle;

  public RotatingEllipse(float startX, float startY) {

    rotateAroundX = (width/2 + startX)/2;
    rotateAroundY = (height/2 + startY)/2;

    distanceFromRotatingPoint = dist(startX, startY, rotateAroundX, rotateAroundY);

    angle = atan2(startY-height/2, startX-width/2);
  }

  public void stepAndDraw() {

    angle += PI/64;

    float x = rotateAroundX + cos(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;
    float y = rotateAroundY + sin(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;

    float distance = dist(x, y, width/2, height/2);
    float diameter = 50*(500-distance)/500;

    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }
}
```

Try clicking or dragging in this example. User interaction makes more sense to me using this approach, but which option you choose really depends on what fits inside your head the best.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will study this code and report back!

Comment: I've been looking over the code of option two and am curious on moving further with adding more ellipses. I just want to completely understand how you determined the initial positions of the first 4 ellipses. When you say I may need some basic trig to figure out the positions, is that way you are referring to in order to obtain what position to place each additional pair of ellipses. Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaGarcia The initial positions were just hard-coded to be in the 4 corners of the window. I then use basic trig (specifically the `atan2()` function) to figure out its starting `angle`, and then I use the `cos()` and `sin()` functions to figure out its position based on changing that angle. Feel free to post another question if you don't understand something.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I attempt at placing an ellipse in between the two outer ellipses why does it result outside of the "square" of ellipses. I figured that by dividing the distance of width/2 and height/2 and multiplying by the same amount it would work. Nevertheless, I'm placing an illustration into the original post that diagrams exactly what I am trying to achieve when the ellipses are unanimated.

Comment: @JoshuaGarcia It'll be easier if you post any follow-up questions in their own post. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for continued discussion after the original question was answered. If you tag it with [tag:processing], I'll see it.