# Processing - Line in direction of mouse pointer

Tags: processing

I am trying to achieve an effect like the image below

[image]

In my code, I managed to create this effect but in repeating the effect it seems to multiply inwards on itself. Could anyone help me to make my code achieve the effect in the image above?

```
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  frameRate(60);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  smooth();
  loop();
}

void draw() {

  background(#ffffff);

  //border
  strokeWeight(3);
  fill(255);
  arc(50, 50, 50, 50, -PI, -PI / 2);
  fill(255);
  arc(450, 450, 50, 50, 0, PI / 2.0);
  line(25, 50, 25, 475);
  line(25, 475, 450, 475);
  line(475, 450, 475, 25);
  line(475, 25, 135, 25);
  fill(0);
  text("MAGNETS", 60, 30);

  //Lines    
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
  drawMagnet();
}
}

  float angle = 0;
  int x = 75;
  int y = 75;
  float tAngle = 0;
  float easing = 0.1f;

void drawMagnet(){

    int l = 10; //length

    angle = atan2( mouseY - y, mouseX - x);

    float dir = (angle - tAngle) / TWO_PI;
    dir -= round(dir);
    dir *= TWO_PI;

    tAngle += dir * easing;

    stroke(0);
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(tAngle);
    line(-l, 0, l, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rotations and translations are stacking, which is causing your problem. To fix this, you might do something like this:

```
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x, y);
  rotate(tAngle);
  line(-l, 0, l, 0);
  popMatrix();
```

Here I'm using the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions so your rotations and translations don't stack.

But then all of your lines are at the same `x,y` location. So they'll all have the same angle towards the mouse position.

You're using the `translate()` function to draw them in different locations, but that doesn't change their underlying "model" position.

Similar to my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015358/calculate-ellipse-size-in-relation-to-distance-from-center-point), you need to either base your calculations off the screen position of the lines (using the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions), or you need to stop relying on `translate()` to move your lines around and calculate their positions directly.