# Array of ellipses rotating along own center point

Tags: processing

This is a continuation of the original post:

[Calculate ellipse size in relation to distance from center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015358/calculate-ellipse-size-in-relation-to-distance-from-center-point)

I am trying to create a grid of ellipses that all rotate along their own center of rotation. Then, I am trying to scale that "square grid" of ellipses by a center point while still allowing them to rotate along their own individual center points.

[image: Multiple ellipses + Scale by center]

```java
ArrayList<RotatingEllipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<RotatingEllipse>();


void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  noStroke();
  smooth();

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.75));

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.75));

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2*.25, height/2*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2*.75, height/2*.75));

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2*.75, height/2*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2*.25, height/2*.75));
}

void draw() {
  background(#202020);

  for (RotatingEllipse e : ellipses) {
    e.stepAndDraw();
  }
}


class RotatingEllipse {

  float rotateAroundX;
  float rotateAroundY;
  float distanceFromRotatingPoint;
  float angle;

  public RotatingEllipse(float startX, float startY) {

    rotateAroundX = (width/2 + startX)/2;
    rotateAroundY = (height/2 + startY)/2;


    distanceFromRotatingPoint = dist(startX, startY, rotateAroundX,    rotateAroundY);

    angle = atan2(startY-height/2, startX-width/2);
  }

  public void stepAndDraw() {


    angle += PI/128;


    float x = rotateAroundX + cos(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;
    float y = rotateAroundY + sin(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;



    float distance = dist(x, y, width/2, height/2); 

// size of ellipses  
    float diameter = 50*(200-distance)/500;
   ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question though? What about this updated code isn't working how you expect it to?

Comment: I added the wrong code, I attached the correct part which is just adding ellipses. I thought that adding width/2 and height/2 would allow an ellipse to be put in between the two outer ellipses, but the outcome is far different. The question is more or less related to the diagram which is asking how I add ellipses in between the two outer ellipses and how I can scale all of those rotating ellipses by a center point. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question has two parts.

**Part 1: Why are your points showing up where they are?**

The best thing you can do to understand where things will be is to get out a piece of paper and a pencil and draw out some points. Where will each of your points show up?

[image]

Processing is putting your points exactly where you're telling it to put them. Here's an example:

```java
ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2*.25, height/2*.75));
```

Where do you expect that to show up? If your width and height are both `500`, then `width/2*.25` will be `62.5` and `height/2*.75` will be `187.5`. In other words, this will be somewhere in the upper-left quadrant of your screen.

Do that math for every one of your ellipses, and you'll see exactly why they're showing up where they are.

**Part 2: How can you calculate the midpoint between two points?**

This is more a math question than a programming question, and googling something like "midpoint between two points" returns a ton of results.

But basically, if you have two points at `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`, then you can find their midpoint by averaging their `x` and `y` positions:

`midpoint = (x1+x2)2, (y1+y2)/2`

I suggest you work through the first part to figure out where your points should be, then use the second part to find midpoints between those points.

Comment: After writing everything out the location became much more clear. Thank you